get characters and shorten folder name, applescript to extendscript
In Applescript, I use the below to get a folder on my desktop whose name ends with "PROOF"
(the folders full name name is:  A123456-PROOF ), it then removes the characters "-PROOF"
leaving me with A123456, How would this be done usingextendscript?, can I get some help and pointers with this please?
cheers
Kev
set _folders to (folders of desktop whose name ends with "PROOF")
    repeat with _folder in _folders
        set _Name to name of _folder
        set name of _folder to (characters 1 thru -7 of _Name as text)
        
    end repeat

Iv'e looked at "split", but i'm not sure how to use it properly

Something like this?
var folders = Folder.desktop.getFiles("*-PROOF");
while (f = folders.pop()) f.rename(f.name.split('-')[0]);

Or here is the almost exact translation of your code:
var folders = Folder.desktop.getFiles("*PROOF");
for (var i=0; i<folders.length; i++) {
    var new_name = folders[i].name.slice(0,7);
    folders[i].rename(new_name);
}


Thankyou very much, this is great to learn from,  so "split" and "slice" are diiferent but do the same thing, so for what I asked would the better option be to split?,

As you can see there are two different approaches. Slice takes first six letters. Split splits a name into two halves (by '-') and takes the first half. I think it makes sense to chose the approach which will be more error-proof in your workflow. Say if there are chances that a folder will have the name like 'A12345-PROOF' or 'A123456_PROOF' some day? Which of these errors is more likely? And what the result is less harmful? It could be the answer on the question.

thnakyou Yuri, makes for a good approach, appreciate your time.
